# getting the values of checkboxes in a checkboxlist control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp:CheckboxList on my page and I need to get the values of the checked checkboxes.

So I have a linq query that I then loop through, but I've discovered that there is no way to retrieve the values associated with the individual checkboxes.

Here is my code:

```
        Dim checkboxValues = cblmyCheckboxes.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().Where(Function(c) c.Checked)

        For Each c As CheckBox In checkboxValues
            Response.Write(c.Value)
        Next
```

How can I get the values?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  And just out of curiosity, why LINQ?

Comment: Did you SET a value for your checkboxes?

Comment: Yes values are set, and I get an error that says value is not a member of CheckBox

Comment: I used to linq to get all the checkboxes that are checked, then I am looping through those...

Comment: @999cm999 - I know **what** you used LINQ for - I was just curious as to **WHY** you used LINQ, rather than a simple loop.  I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm just genuinely curious is all.

Comment: @Tim Oh sorry, sometimes I feel as LINQ is an eloquent way of coding so I decided to use it just for that reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Checkbox List contains `ListItem` and not checkbox. So cblmyCheckboxes.Items is a `ListItemCollection`

Really, a quicker and easier way would be:

```
For Each li as ListItem in cblmyCheckboxes.Items
       If (li.Selected) Then
           Dim XX = li.Value
          '' Do something with Value
       End If
Next
```

By using LINQ you're effectively looping through the checkbox lists items (in the background of your LINQ function (which is wrong anyway) and then also looping again in your `For Each` - might as well just do the one...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Selected` instead of `Checked`

```
var selectedValues = (CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
.Where(i => i.Selected)
.Select(i => i.Value))
.ToList();

Dim selectedValues = (CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)()
.Where(Function(i) i.Selected)
.[Select](Function(i) i.Value))
.ToList()
```